# How can I add a user and specify a password for a in IBM Data Studio?

Tags: db2, authentication, db2-luw, db2-10.5, ibm-data-studio

In Data Studio I can connect to a sever/database, go down to Users And Groups, right-click on Users and add a new one. But the program never asks me for a password. How can I specify it?

Also, no matter how many times I tried to "Save changes" they are never saved. I even tried to "generate change" and run it, but it always fails.

I am connecting as the only user that exists on the server: db2admin. If db2admin has no authority to manage users, then who has?

Answer (score 1):

Eventually I found that DB2 UDB does not have its own repository for users, unlike other database servers. DB2 relies on the OS for user management. In Windows, for instance, after creating a UDB user, one has to go into Windows Control Panel/User Accounts and add that same user. Then UDB will allow it to log in with the password, supplied on the OS level. I presume that in Linux the procedure is similar: add a user in UDB, then run CLI commands to add a user and to change its password.